# A Menu with Two Columns?

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I'm attempting to figure out how to introduce a second column to Material's Menu, but am finding controlling two using the same View Controller's menu delegate methods tricky. Might there be a trivial way to accomplish this that I haven't thought of? I could probably make another View Controller be a second Menu's delegate, but this doesn't seem an elegant solution.

Cheers!

Comment: Post some of your already tried code, I think using the two viewControllers is the best way to handle the delegates, this way code will be modularised and will be simple. It is easy to understand this from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Menu` object itself, and not the `MenuController`, you should be able to do a compare in the delegation method, where you compare the menu being called with your view controller declaration property for either `Menu`. For example:

```
extension ViewController: MenuDelegate {
    func menu(menu: Menu, tappedAt point: CGPoint, isOutside: Bool) {

        if menu == menuA {

        } else if menu == menuB {

        }
    }
}
```

Now you should only need to do this if the functionality differs for each columns menu. If you need any further help, please share you code :)